# Filtering data in range to populate drop-down menu

Tags: drop-down-menu, google-apps-script, filter, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet which serves as a form for listing equipment in a contract. In a given row, selecting a distributor(col F) populates the Manufacturer field(col E) with a drop-down menu based on data in another sheet. What I need now is for the Model field(col D) to populate with a drop-down list based on the filtering of a series of ranges I've already defined (l01,l11,l12,l13), for the value from col E.

Here's my code so far:

```
function onEdit() 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
  sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
  name = sheet.getName();
  if (name != 'Addendum B') return;
  var range = sheet.getActiveRange(),
      col = range.getColumn();
  if (col != 5) return;
  var val = range.getValue(),
      ctlg0 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1nbCJOkpIQxnn71sJPj6X4KaahROP5cMg1SI9xIeJdvY"),
      ctlg1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Jzue8G0dAJC5CiY5_s-thaOiYEyfeJScb2ITNWa_dVQ"),
      c01 = ctlg0.getSheetByName('MISC_CATALOG'),
      c11 = ctlg1.getSheetByName('Part #A-I'),
      c12 = ctlg1.getSheetByName('Part #J-R'),
      c13 = ctlg1.getSheetByName('Part #S-9'),
      l01 = c01.getRange("A2:B"),
      l11 = c11.getRange("A2:B"),
      l12 = c12.getRange("A2:B"),
      l13 = c13.getRange("A2:B"),
      //data = dv.getDataRange().getValues(),
      //catCol = data[0].indexOf(val),
      //list = [];
  Logger.log(catCol)
  for (var i = 1, len = 100; i < len; i++)
      list.push(data[i][catCol]);
  var listRange = dv.getRange(2,catCol +1,dv.getLastRow() - 1, 1)
  Logger.log(list)
  var cell = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), col-1)
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInRange(listRange)  
  .build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);
  Logger.log(cell.getRow())
}
```

I've commented out the place where I ran out of coding knowledge to implement this myself. The above code is based on my existing data validation for col E. Sample sheets can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B1-BYilDJaZMdnhVdDJKUmVUamM?usp=sharing).

I have a basic understanding of coding, and have mostly taught myself by breaking down sample code and reading the GAS online reference material. Any assistance with this would be helpful, but please provide as much detail as you  can by way of explanation so I can hopefully learn how to adapt this solution to future projects.

Comment: I can't see any validation values for column 5.  I see a range is defined E2:E10000 but there is no data there in XREF.  Since you want Addendum B why not just `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Addendum B')` and save yourself a lot of extra coding.  I never use commas in the declaration so I'm wondering, Does it all have to end in a `; `? If so then where is your semicolon before `Logger.log(catCol)`.

Comment: I recommend that you take a couple steps back do some simple spreadsheets and maybe some more tutorials.  Don't worry about the formatting just focus on learning a little coding.  Pay attention to the way the code editor syntax highlights declared variables and play around with the debugger and code completion.  Also play around with getValues and setValues.  After that come back and tackle this problem again.  You might find it a lot easier to figure out.

Comment: @Cooper, thanks for your response. I'm sorry that I don't entirely understand it as an answer to my question. I asked about accomplishing a specific goal, and instead of helping you poorly critiqued my existing work. 


`I can't see any validation values for column 5.` As noted in my question, these values are determined by selecting a distributor in col 6.


`I see a range is defined E2:E10000 but there is no data there in XREF.` I don't know what range you're referring to (E2:E10000 of what sheet, and where is it referenced?)

Comment: `Since you want Addendum B why not just...` I'm not trying to retrieve the data in the sheet, the code you refer to is meant to verify that the onEdit trigger occurred on, and is acting upon the correct sheet in the set.
`I never use commas...` Commas just save from having to begin every declaration line with `var`. They separate your terms and then the entire declaration is closed with a `;`. `If so then where is your semicolon before Logger.log(catCol)` It's exactly where it should be, at the end of the line preceding it.